# Discord bot: removing a specific role from a specific user

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, roles

Let me start of saying - I am a total newb to javascript, as well as discord with javascript.

With that said, I have a string that was determined elsewhere in the code, Username. This string is literally the discord username (I.E. username#1234) for a specific member of the server this bot is running in. I am trying to remove a role from this user, via the line:

```
message.guild.Username.roles.remove('roleid');
```

instead, it returns the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined`

Am I not able to use a string in this manner? If not, how can I remove this person's role another way? Any help appreciated!

Comment: `message.guild.Username` is `undefined`. It does not exist. Hence the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined`. You say you are using Java and JavaScript. They are not the same language. You said `Username` is a string. A string does not have a property `roles`. You need to create a Member object from the library you are using. That Member object will have a property called `roles`.

Comment: I haven't used objects before - and am totally clueless. This is probably not at all what you mean, but... am I on the right track? https://pastebin.com/kdSujvL1

Comment: Forgive the random console log in there btw - that doesn't do anything for this segment atm

Comment: Which Discord JS version are you using? You can check that in `package.json`.

Answer (score -1):

```
`message.guild.Username.roles.remove('roleid');`
```

Instead you have to type:
`const Username = 'username#1234';`
`message.guild.(Username).removeRole('roleid')`

Comment: that wont work, it will think that Username is a property of guild object when it's not. And you cant defined variables as a property either